# How do I get my slicer to automatically update based on a data validation dropdown selection?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, slicers

I wrote some code below to have my pivot table's filters (in the slicer) update when a data validation dropdown is changed. So far, this is what I have but it is not working:

```
Option Explicit

' sheet module
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim sc As SlicerCache, si As SlicerItem
    If Target.Address = "$F$2" Then                        ' cell to monitor
        Set sc = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Concat")      ' desired slicer
        sc.ClearAllFilters
        For Each si In sc.SlicerItems
            If si.Caption = CStr(Target) Then
                si.Selected = True
            Else
               si.Selected = False
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm not the best at VBA, so I've read through some old threads on this site and a few mrexcel forums that detail this problem. They all say to use the above code, with the only things I've changed being adding in the `Option Explicit` command and modifying the name of the slicer and the exact target cell.

I first tried using this code in a new module on the sheet, but nothing happened when I updated the contents of cell F2. Then I tried to move the code to the worksheet itself. This at least generated a reaction from excel when I changed the contents of cell F2, but the response was the following error message:

RUN TIME ERROR '1004':
Application-defined or object-defined error

When I go to debug, the error comes up at the following line in my code:

```
For Each si In sc.SlicerItems
```

Does anyone have any ideas where to go from here? The slicer doesn't seem affected by anything I've tried. Not even sure if the code should go in a module or the worksheet itself.

Comment: To answer your last question, yes this belongs in the worksheet.

Comment: Maybe look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/31828030/478884

Comment: Hi Tim, I tried to implement the feedback from that post and it didn't work, and I'm not sure I understand the stagnant reference here in the solution:  If sI.Name = "Introduction To Slicer"